# Jquery Tipsy not working with Jquery 2.1.4?

Tags: jquery, html, tipsy

I've used tipsy many times before over the last 2 years with no issue, but when I try run it on a new site I'm building, it's just not working! Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

It's at [my website](http://dpdesig.nz/spendit/lib/test.html), and I've cut it down to the bare basics but still no luck!

I've called `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`, `<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>`, `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tipsy/1.0.2/jquery.tipsy.css">`, and `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tipsy/1.0.2/jquery.tipsy.min.js"></script>`, with the following code to execute it

```
<div>
    <p class="tipsy-trigger" original-title="View This">Test Tipsy</p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.tipsy-trigger').tipsy({gravity: $.fn.tipsy.autoNS, html: true}); // nw | n | ne | w | e | sw | s | se
    });
</script>
```

The only thing I've done different this time vs any other time is use JQuery 2.1.4.

Comment: Seems to work if you link to [the original js file on the aurthor's site](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/javascripts/jquery.tipsy.js), see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/1o75rxxz/). Could be the CDN version is messed up or maybe it has some requirement that's not met in your use?

Comment: Hmm that's odd. Thanks :)